# Manifest merger failed when increasing targetSDK to 33

Tags: android, targetsdkversion, target-sdk, androidexported, merged-manifest

I have a multi-module Android project and I increased compile and target SDK to 33 in each module, but the problem occurs when increasing the target SDK in the app module.
The error is the following:** android: exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android: exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined.**

Although I set an exported label for each activity.
Also, I solved all errors in the Merged Manifest file.

Kotlin version is "1.7.10" and tools.build:gradle is "7.0.4".

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Is that error message complete? It seems to be missing something after "for".